# Is it possible to have type narrowing in conditional blocks for types conditional upon the presence of an object key?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This is what I have so far:

```
type A = { a: string; b: number | null };

type Conditional<T extends Partial<A>> = T extends { b: number }
  ? {
      always: TimeService;
      onlyIfB: VaultService;
    }
  : {
      always: TimeService;
  };
    
function conditional<T extends Partial<A>>(
    data: T,
    props: Conditional<T>,
  ) {
    if ('b' in data && data.b) {
      console.log(props.always);
      console.log(props.onlyIfB); // this fails
    } else {
      console.log(props.always);
    }
  }
```

Interestingly, the conditional does work. If I do

```
conditional({b: 1},...)
```

, then it requires that I give it `{always, onlyIfB}` for props. if I don't have a `b` key specified, then it is fine with `{always}`. Where it falls apart is the function definition `conditional` above. I'm not sure how to do this such that I can actually access `onlyIfB`. so conditional's type signature works, but the body doesn't type check the way I expected it to. Is there a way of making this work without having to cast or something?

Comment: make overloads.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer! I don't know the interaction of typescript's type system and overloads very well. I can experiment but I'd be super gracious if you could clarify what you mean. I'm still fairly new to typescript

Comment: I've had to explain this kind of thing so many times, so I ended up writing [a page](https://kelsny.github.io/typescript/conditional-type-abuse) that explains why it doesn't work and what you can do about it. ([raw](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kelsny/typescript/master/conditional-type-abuse.md))

Answer (score 1):

Okay, since in your bounty message you say

> hoping to find some sort of way to achieve generally want I want... that is to say, the strategy used to make the type checking work is flexible

Here's a cheat/stupid method. Just do a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions):

```js
function typeAssertion<T>(val: any): asserts val is T {
  // actually a no-op (we don't throw anything) tee-hee
}
function conditional<T extends Partial<A>>(
    data: T,
    props: Conditional<T>,
  ) {
    if ('b' in data && data.b) {
      typeAssertion<{ always: TimeService; onlyIfB: VaultService; }>(props); // <- tada
      console.log(props.always);
      console.log(props.onlyIfB); // this no longer fails
    } else {
      console.log(props.always);
    }
  }
```

Not far-off from that solution is to use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
function isBTypePredicate(props: any): props is { always: TimeService; onlyIfB: VaultService; } {
   return "b" in props;
 }
 function conditional<T extends Partial<A>>(
     data: T,
     props: Conditional<T>,
   ) {
     if (isBTypePredicate(props,)) {
       console.log(props.always);
       console.log(props.onlyIfB); // this no longer fails
     } else {
       console.log(props.always);
     }
   }
```

Note that [@zenly](/users/18244921) has [a writeup on this topic](https://kelsny.github.io/typescript/conditional-type-abuse) with a nice workaround that I couldn't get working for your particular case:

```
type A = { a: string; b: number | null };
    
function conditional<T extends Partial<A>>(...[data,props]:
    [Omit<T,"b">, {always:TimeService}] | [T, {always:TimeService,onlyIfB:VaultService}]
  ) {
    if ('b' in data && data.b) {
      console.log(props.always);
      console.log(props.onlyIfB); // this fails
    } else {
      console.log(props.always);
    }
  }
```

According to zenly, it doesn't work if the discriminatory value is nested (type narrowing does not propagate to parent objects). You would have to add b as a parameter by itself instead.

Lastly, you could write this with overloads, but it *wouldn't give you any type narrowing inside the conditional blocks*:

```
type A = { a: string; b: number | null };

function conditional<T extends Partial<A>>(data: Omit<T,"b">, props: {always:TimeService}): any;
function conditional<T extends Partial<A>>(data: T, props: {always:TimeService,onlyIfB:VaultService}): any;
function conditional<T extends Partial<A>>(data: T, props: {always:TimeService,onlyIfB?:VaultService}) {
  if ('b' in data && data.b) {
    console.log(props.always);
    console.log(props.onlyIfB);
  } else {
    console.log(props.always);
  }
}
```

As for why what you originally wrote isn't working, it's probably just a type narrowing case that hasn't been implemented yet, though parts of it are: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#unlisted-property-narrowing-with-the-in-operator. This issue ticket might be related, but I'm not 100% sure on that: [Conditional types are incorrectly narrowed #30152](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30152). Also potentially related: [Relate control flow to conditional types in return types #33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).

If you decide to research existing TypeScript issue tickets (Ex. googling "`github typescript issues property narrowing in conditional`" and other related queries), don't find one that seems to capture your issue, and decide to open your own issue ticket, I suggest simplifying your repro a bit. Ex.

```js
type Data = { a: string; b?: number };

type Props<T extends Partial<Data>> = T extends { b: number }
  ? { always: number; onlyIfB: number; }
  : { always: number; };

function conditional<T extends Partial<Data>>(
  data: T,
  props: Props<T>,
) {
  if ('b' in data && data.b) {
    console.log(props.always);
    console.log(props.onlyIfB); // Property 'onlyIfB' does not exist on type 'Conditional<T>'. ts(2339)
    // expected: property narrowing with the `in` operator would narrow `props` to { always: number; onlyIfB: number; }
    // actual: `props` is still treated as `Conditional<T>` in this `if` block.
  } else {
    console.log(props.always);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oof, this reminds me of an edit I need to make. This doesn't work if the discriminatory value is nested (type narrowing does not propagate to parent objects). You would have to [add `b` as a parameter](https://tsplay.dev/m3BObN) by itself instead.

Answer (score 0):

The logic you want out of TypeScript isn't actually sound, because there's no guarantee that `data` and `props` haven't been modified between calling the function and applying the conditional. In other words, the relationship they had when calling the function may not still exist. Take this example:

```
function conditional<T extends Partial<A>>(data: T, props: Conditional<T>) {
  data.b = 1;
  if (typeof data.b === 'number') {
    console.log(props.always);
    console.log(props.onlyIfB); // Throws error, like it should
  } else {
    console.log(props.always);
  }
}
```

The assignment to `data.b` is sound, but if TypeScript inferred that `props` had an `onlyIfB` property, it would be incorrect.

---

You can force TypeScript to use your logic with a [Type Predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

```
type A = { a: string; b: number | null };

type Props1 = {
  always: TimeService;
  onlyIfB: VaultService;
}

type Props2 = {
  always: TimeService;
};

type Conditional<T extends Partial<A>> = T extends { b: number } ? Props1 : Props2;

function isProps1<T extends Partial<A>>(data: T, props: Conditional<T>): props is Props1 {
  return typeof data.b === 'number';
}

function conditional<T extends Partial<A>>(data: T, props: Conditional<T>) {
  if (isProps1(data, props)) {
    console.log(props.always);
    console.log(props.onlyIfB); // No error, TypeScript trusts your judgement
  } else {
    console.log(props.always);
  }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCWBbApgZWQJwG72Mg3gL4DcAUKJDAGpgCuIALutrgSaaQwJ4AOy0AQWgBeaPmhgAXNAgMM8AHYBzYtABG0hbURrM0AD7QtIENHade-AAoYA9jwgBGEWNLQJIAO5guEaQhRmHDwyd1sFEC4ASQAzACFpGnomTGDkMkIObj5oG3sIACYXfDcPb19-JDRU1gyyCxyAYXCAE3gGeHCwEAAeWGhkAA8GZAUWmCswDA7unoEAPnmXfqGRsZhxDSNtXQwzaAB+XLsHZ2k8hwL6mNoFYA7w6HgIC6c+geHR8dypmd6F+YAChaYAYUjgABpoDwTn5oM0xu1OgpZrB5gBKaQw-JPCaw5wldwYZAMWgYBTQbLIWwxaAgsEAOjUImEogA5FodJg2RkODc7g8KcBWkiur0Vp91j9pvBZgDgaDwbAodiHNIEW1BaiMa53O54LTAc9Xo4FWCVbD0ejdXr3MKFBBbCBkAyQLYlIDVRAGd1yhB0aFbdB7Y7na73Z7YQzwpFYnEA6V3IQBiAIPxCUGQ06XW6PV6fV4fP7A0nSJkgA)

---

However it's still up to you to keep the type predicate and the use of it logically sound, so I wouldn't exactly call this pattern type safe. Usually when type checking gets this complex it's a flag that there's a better pattern to use. For example, just making two separate functions may be the best solution, instead of trying to make one function do two different things.

```js
function f1(data: {b: number}, props: Props1) {
  console.log(props.always);
  console.log(props.onlyIfB);
}

function f2(data: Partial<A>, props: Props2) {
  console.log(props.always);
}
```

It's hard to tell without knowing the exact use case.

Comment: I don't really get the first argument about modifications to the type. the parameter type annotation is a contract. The contract is assumed by tsc to hold true, and it will generally ignore if you do something to break it inside the body of the function. If it's true generally, why worry about it for this specific case?

Comment: @user that's not modifying the type of `data`.  `data` is a `Partial<A>` which means assigning to `b` is fine. So the inference you're trying to make will not always be true. The contract you made regarding the relationship between the two parameters only applies when calling the function. Inside the function, TypeScript only knows that `data extends Partial<A>` and `props` could be `Props1` or `Props2`.

Comment: "_The contract you made only applies when calling the function, not inside of it._" well, yes. That's what I said, isn't it? And then I said "_If it's true generally, why worry about it for this specific case?_" And what about the runtime check is wrong? As far as I can tell, if you do type narrowing in static blocks based on a runtime check in the condition part of the if-block, that's fine.

Comment: @user I'm not sure what you mean by TypeScript ignoring contracts being broken inside the body of the function, that's not something that should happen.

Comment: @user Yes you can do a runtime check to see if `props` is of type `Props1`, for example with a class and the `instanceof` operator. But you can't expect TypeScript to infer the `props` type after narrowing the `data` type. Sure it seems simple in this example, but building that into TypeScript to work in all cases would be incredibly complex, if it's even possible.

Comment: "_I'm not sure what you mean by TypeScript ignoring contracts being broken inside the body of the function, that's not something that should happen._" (should and can are two separate things :P): `function a(b: { c: number }) { Object.assign(b, {c:null}); console.log(b); }`

Comment: @user If not defining a generic, `Object.assign` has two possible signatures: `assign(target: {}, source: unknown): {}` or `assign(target: object, ...sources: any[]): any` - you can enforce types using generics `Object.assign<typeof b, typeof b>(b,{c:null});  //error`.  The type contract of `b` is being broken inside of `Object.assign` which is a native JavaScript function, so you can't really expect TypeScript to stop you from shooting yourself in the foot there.